# Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden

Tags: ruby, firebase

`Httparty` post response is coming as

```
#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>

request = HTTParty.post('http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
 :body => { "to" => "xxx:xxxx", "priority" => "high", "data" => { "title" =>"test","body"=>"cccc",'massage_type'=>'text'}}.to_json, :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => "key=cccccc","User-Agent"=>"" } )
```

Comment: What is the question?  Create a How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Its fixed now by using legacy key instead using API_key from google-services.json which is no deprecated now